# How can I update all spring objects after setting new configuration?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration, autowired

How can I refresh previously `@Autowired` spring objects after dynamic configuration changes?

```
// Here is my updateConfig method

GenericApplicationContext context = new GenericApplicationContext();
XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context);
reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml"));
context.refresh();

myApplicationContextAware.setApplicationContext(context);
```

With `myApplicationContextAware.applicationContext.getBean(MyClass.class)` I can get new instances by new configuration, but all `@Autowired` objects still contain old values

Is there any solution to refresh spring objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.html) for this. It provides methods to reload bean configuration in run time.

If you're using spring boot then you can use [@RefreshScope](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope) annotation with the [spring actuator](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_endpoints). Spring actuator endpoint `/refresh` reloads the beans annotated with @RefreshScope.

Comment: Spring Boot works perfectly, thank you! 

Otherwise AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext doesn't work for me, it loads the new config anyway but even that all initially autowired beans contain old values

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I also found SO entries that refreshable context does not update references to old beans.