# Spring - Providing @Autowired at runtime

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have a program that's being called as a web service, from another web service, actually.  The caller of my program converts the input (which is the input to my program too) to JSON, and then calls my program, passing the JSON in.  My program converts it (through GSON) to Java code.  Keep in mind that the input is in a jar file that's included in my pom.  Is there a way to autowire a part of the input?

What I've done so far is to put `@Component` on the part I want to autowire, called SystemInfo:

```
@Component
public class SystemInfo {
    protected String GUID;
    protected String EntityID;
    protected Double EpisodeNumber;
    protected Double ErrorCode;
    protected String ErrorMesg;
    protected String Facility;
    protected String NamespaceName;
    protected String OptionId;
    protected String OptionStaffId;
    protected String OptionUserId;
    protected String ParentNamespace;
    protected String ServerName;
    protected String SystemCode;
    protected String WarName;
    protected String ScriptName;

    /**
     * @return the gUID
     */
    public String getGUID() {
        return GUID;
    }
<other setters and getters>
```

I've set up an ApplicationConfig.java that consists of:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.mhcd.avatar.model")
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

I put that in the jar so it would see the `@Component`.  I put in the xml for my program:

```
<bean id="systemInfo"
    class="org.mhcd.avatar.model.domainLayer.SystemInfo"
    autowire="byType" autowire-candidate="true">
</bean>
```

Then, I put in my program:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

and

```
GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext(context);
ctx.refresh();
```

The refresh I put after I converted the JSON to Java objects.  I put `@Autowired` in front of the SystemInfo in my DAO objects, and I stepped through my DAOs in debug, and SystemInfo is null.  I'm thinking there must be a way to do this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: what you want to do is autowire a transfer object that you receive in you webservice ? Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update all spring objects after setting new configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501508/how-can-i-update-all-spring-objects-after-setting-new-configuration)

Comment: @reos Yes, that's it exactly.  I want to do this because the logger requires it.  (The logger is based on log4j 2 and writes to the database.)  The part I want to `@Autowired` contains a lot of information.

Comment: have you forgot to import your xml in application configuration?

Comment: @kuhajeyan No, I don't think so.  The xml appears in my program (web service).  The application configuration shows up in the jar that contains SystemInfo.

Comment: I don't understand how you would use that object as a bean. For me it's a transfer object. If you would use this object in the log, I think it was as a transfer object. It's the same when you save an store in the database, you don't have spring beans of dto/transfers objects, you have beans of the DAO and Service objects.

Comment: @reos I've edited my question.  Maybe it will make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up and took out almost all the Spring annotations.  I still have `@RestController`, some `@Component`, and a sprinkling of `@Autowired` and `@Repository`.  I got around this issue by putting this in all my DAOs:

```
private SystemInfo systemInfo;
public void init(SystemInfo systemInfo) {
    this.systemInfo = systemInfo;
}
```

I then called the init method before doing any work, providing systemInfo as an argument.

There must be some way to do this as an `@Autowired` sort of thing, but I don't know what it is.